# How to make netbeans auto generated annotation use getters not fields

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, netbeans, annotations

I am using netbeans to create entity class from database. but it uses property fields for hibernate annotations. i want annotations on getters.

how can i do that

Comment: what would be the difference ?

Comment: the code looks easy to read , especially the fields, otherwise it becomes difficult to see what are the fields in class with annotations on top

Comment: Hibernate uses the getters if the annotation is on the method, otherwise it uses direct field access. This produce differences if the getter can change the value of its associated field.

Comment: Moreover, if you annotate getters instead of fields, you can use javafx objects as fields enabling bidirectional yet controlled binding.